# WeChat Integration to my android application for login

Tags: android, authentication, integration, wechat

I have appId and appSecret of WeChat and also conform the package name.But not pass to WeChat allow dialog.I am done with WeChat Demo. But After Login, I got errCode "-6". If any one have idea about this, please help me and any suggestions are welcome for this.

Comment: i have also same problem.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?